# SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have added the `AutoPostBack = "true"` attribute to the drop down list. 
It doesn't work.

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dropDownList" ID="ddlBusinessUnit" 
                  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="250px"   
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

code behind:

```
Protected Sub ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Write("Hello")
End
```

How can I ensure that the event method is called?

Comment: This is a little vague.  Is the DropDownList actually populated with anything?  If so, when you select, are you selecting a different value or the one that was already selected?  You'll need to select a new value if you want to post back. [Ed] also - I'm with the other commenters; Response.Write() can get lost depending on what else is on your page.  Stick a breakpoint in it!

Comment: @abhi: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in that method?

Comment: Are you using any updatepanels... ?

Comment: looks right to me...you did put a breakpoint and see right ?

Comment: Yes it is being populated. I have tried selecting other values than the one displayed as the first item.

Comment: Don't you repopulate the drop-down list before postback event handling? See Page Life Cycle Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Vote up because mine was missing AutoPostBack and OnSelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating your Dropdownlist on every Postback?

Use [IsPostBack](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx&ei=1jXQTIDYFsyhOuSq-coF&usg=AFQjCNGAiaaCkfLAq0fgFtAPr0ZRuAy5nQ&sig2=hwAEMIbSPBOVkymN16Bddg) to check whether the page is loaded for the first time or not.

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   BinDdlBusinessUnit()
End If
```