# OnSelectedIndexChange event is not firing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to execute the event but it does not work. I've tried to fix the
problem by adding `AutoPostBack = "true"`, but it did not work. I've also tried to
activate the same event on another `DropDownList` without success.

```html
<div class="col-sm-3" style="float: left">
  <div class="input-group input-group-md" style="padding-top: 6px; width: 308px;">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" Width="250px" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
     fillCity(Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079566)?

Comment: I oppose this to be closed as duplicate. User has already used AutoPostBack in this problem.

Comment: If the question marked as duplicate serves your purpose then good enough. Otherwise see this link to how to Re-open the question.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217393/falsely-duplicate-question-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AutoPostBack` Is must for Dropdownlist to fire `SelectedIndexChange` event. Since this you have already tried. See following.

Your question is showing partial html of your page, but I am sure there might be more input controls. You must try to see following :

1. If there are some `RequiredFieldValidators` make sure they are not getting fired (validated) for any missing input.
2. Try CausesValidation=«false» on dropdown list, in case any validation is firing, this will avoid it being fired.

If 1 & 2 is not the case then try putting these dropdownlist out of any parent container and run test again.